# Convert multidimensional array in custom form

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have array

```
     $arr = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '340',
    'days' => '1',
    'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00',
    'end_date' => '2018-10-13 00:00:00',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '346',
    'days' => '2',
    'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00',
    'end_date' => '2018-10-14 00:00:00',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '339',
    'days' => '3',
    'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00',
    'end_date' => '2018-10-15 00:00:00',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '302',
    'days' => '4',
    'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00',
    'end_date' => '2018-10-16 00:00:00',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '308',
    'days' => '5',
    'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00',
    'end_date' => '2018-10-17 00:00:00',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => '354',
    'days' => '1',
    'start_date' => '2018-10-13 00:00:00',
    'end_date' => '2018-10-14 00:00:00',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'id' => '369',
    'days' => '1',
    'start_date' => '2018-10-14 00:00:00',
    'end_date' => '2018-10-15 00:00:00',
  )
);
```

**Output:**

```
$arr = array (

      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => '308',
        'days' => '5',
        'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00',
        'end_date' => '2018-10-17 00:00:00',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => '354',
        'days' => '1',
        'start_date' => '2018-10-13 00:00:00',
        'end_date' => '2018-10-14 00:00:00',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'id' => '369',
        'days' => '1',
        'start_date' => '2018-10-14 00:00:00',
        'end_date' => '2018-10-15 00:00:00',
      )
    );
```

Condition :

I want remove duplicate 'start_date' i.e. start_date = 2018-10-12 with lowest number of 'days' and only preserve the date which consists of higher number of days. I have tried using mysql query but I have not got desired output also I have tried array_unique() with numeric format parameter but I have not got any success yet. Help is appreciated. Thanks In advance.

Comment: The would be to do this in SQL. PHP would be the second choice.

Comment: The output which is displayed is from mysql query I tried using subquery though but number of days I received was from different column and start_date i received was from diffrent column

Comment: It is a bit misleading that you include the output you **don't** want to get. It is better to specify more clearly what you **want** to get. Well, I am not sure which way you really want it, since you say that this output is what you get in SQL; but then you say your SQL returns the wrong output. I am confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do that in PHP:

```
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $key = $row["start_date"];
    if (!isset($result[$key]) || $result[$key]["days"] < $row["days"]) {
        $result[$key] = $row;
    }
}

$result = array_values($result);
```

Note the `<` in the `if` condition: this ensures you get the records with the greatest number of days. Switch to `>` to get the least number of days instead.

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Sort your array of arrays from lowest to highest using the `days` column values.

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b){ return $a['days'] <=> $b['days'];});
```

*coincidentally, this step can be avoided because your data is already in a suitable order.

Step #2: Use array column to assign associative keys to each subarray.  As a rule, arrays cannot contain duplicate keys, so earlier rows are overwritten (removed) by later rows -- this yields the desired result.  `array_values()` is called to remove the temporary keys.

```
var_export(array_values(array_column($arr, null, 'start_date')));
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/o5K0s))

```
$arr = [
    ['id' => '340', 'days' => '1', 'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00', 'end_date' => '2018-10-13 00:00:00'],
    ['id' => '346', 'days' => '2', 'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00', 'end_date' => '2018-10-14 00:00:00'],
    ['id' => '339', 'days' => '3', 'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00', 'end_date' => '2018-10-15 00:00:00'],
    ['id' => '302', 'days' => '4', 'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00', 'end_date' => '2018-10-16 00:00:00'],
    ['id' => '308', 'days' => '5', 'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00', 'end_date' => '2018-10-17 00:00:00'],
    ['id' => '354', 'days' => '1', 'start_date' => '2018-10-13 00:00:00', 'end_date' => '2018-10-14 00:00:00'],
    ['id' => '369', 'days' => '1', 'start_date' => '2018-10-14 00:00:00', 'end_date' => '2018-10-15 00:00:00']
];

usort($arr, function($a, $b){ return $a['days'] <=> $b['days'];});
var_export(array_values(array_column($arr, null, 'start_date')));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '308',
    'days' => '5',
    'start_date' => '2018-10-12 00:00:00',
    'end_date' => '2018-10-17 00:00:00',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '354',
    'days' => '1',
    'start_date' => '2018-10-13 00:00:00',
    'end_date' => '2018-10-14 00:00:00',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '369',
    'days' => '1',
    'start_date' => '2018-10-14 00:00:00',
    'end_date' => '2018-10-15 00:00:00',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no any default function for so this so use logic and other available array functions

```
`$result = array();

 $start_date=array();


foreach ($arr as $ele) {

  if(!in_array($ele['start_date'],$start_date)
  {
     $result[]=$ele;
  }    
 $start_date[]=$ele['start_date'];

 }
print_r($result); `
```

May be its helpful for you

Comment: @PriyankaSankhala, I did not downvote, but your code does not verify whether the number of days is the greatest/smallest (see question).

Comment: Always test your code before posting an answer when possible. `in_arr()` is going to cause problems.  Your answer could use some better explanation as well.

Comment: @mickmackusa:- acceptable in_arr() is due to typo  but anyone can make edit it, its not a such a big issue

Comment: Now that this is fixed, I should state for future readers that `in_array()` is slower than `isset()` and this answer generates two arrays when only one is desired.  For this reason, the other answers are better suited for this task.  Please explain to future readers how your answer works, remove the backticks, and improve the tabbing in your snippet.

Comment: Furthermore, `$start_date[]` should be inside the `if` block because your current code is storing redundant data in the lookup array. While it delivers the desired output, there really isn't anything advisable in this answer relative to the other answers.